# Kafka - Consumer - C# - How do I access consumer functionality

Tags: c#, apache-kafka, consumer

A stream of Data should go from one topic through a consumer into a producer into the next topic.
I am writing it in C#.
Currently I am either getting stuck in an infinite loop when I readFromTopic or I break out via a very ugly counter that counts to 10.

I do not have consumer.Consume().poll or any similar method for that matter. I do not know why but they don't show up.
My usings are using System;

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using KafkaNet;
using KafkaNet.Model;
```

here's my code that's working but ugly

```
     private static string readFromTopic(Uri uri, string topic)
    {
        string return = "";
        int count = 0;
        var options = new KafkaOptions(uri);
        var brokerRouter = new BrokerRouter(options);
        var consumer = new Consumer(new ConsumerOptions(topic, brokerRouter));
        foreach (var msg in consumer.Consume())
        {
            returnAmounts += Encoding.UTF8.GetString(msg.Value) + "|";
            count++;

            if (count > 10)
                return returnAmounts;                
        }
        return "";
    }
```

Is my error outside of the function? If not, how can I fix my function.

Have a nice day.

Comment: From : return ""; To : return returnAmounts;

Comment: @jd That shouldn't matter because the for loop is actually infinite, so the only possible return statement will be when the count is over 10

Comment: @Psy What exactly "doesn't show up"? You've not shown any producer code and returnAmounts is not defined anywhere. Keep in mind that your parameters should really just be a consumer instance ; that way you can mock it with a unit test